# Read binary file into Python 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I have a large binary file that I want to read as a 48x1414339 array. I read it in this way:

```
f = open(fname, 'rb')
s = f.read()
import array
a = array.array('f',s)
```

But this gives me a 1D string. Is there a way to keep the columns distinct?

Comment: I would suggest you look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) if you're planning on doing operations on 2D arrays

Comment: Also, a `48x1414339` could be stored in various ways... do you know how to reform it back to its meaningful representation?

Comment: You could make a `list` of 1,414,339 `array` objects each with 48 elements. Regardless, it would also be more efficient to use `array.fromfile()` to read the data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a class and implement e.g. `__getitem__()` to convert an index pair to the linear index. Using separate arrays is probably just adding overhead unless you plan to use rows separately.